# Addin Manager option missing in visual c# 2010 express edition

Tags: visual-studio-express

I have developed a addin in c# 2008 now i want to check in visual c# 2010 express edition
so i have downloaded visual c# 2010 express edition but there is no Add-in Manager option in Tools menu as visual studio 2008 have. and also there is no template for visual studio extensibity in New project menu. 
              So please give me some idea that how can i see Add- in Manager option in 2010 express edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Visual Studio Express versions don't support Add-Ins